SSDT alternative for SQLite?
Is there an equivalent to the SSDT SQL server database project that exists to version control (the schema of) an SQL server database, but for SQLite databases? And if not, what workflow do you use to put your SQLite database schema under version control?
Things I like about SQL server database project and would also like to be able to do for SQLite databases

Being able to import/start the project with an existing database
Being able to diff from the real database and apply changes to the database project
Being able to diff from the database project and apply changes to the real database

What I already found from research is that one could use the SQLite cli tools to extract the schema of your database as a plain text creation script, using the command
sqlite3 MyDatabase.db .schema

And diff using the command
sqldiff MySourceDatabase.db MyTargetDatabase.db

But I'm unsure if this is the way to go, especially since the documentation states that the diff command for example doesn't return changes to Triggers or Views.
